# How do I check a bash script without running the script?

Tags: bash

How do i check for errors (and maybe warnings) in a bash script?

I want to precheck bash scripts before checking them into a git repository.

I know I can use `bash -n script.sh` for a first, simple check but this doen't find for example things like rewriting on a readonly string.

```
readonly unique_id = "42"
unique_id = "21"
```

will be ok for a `bash -n script.sh` but will fail on execution of course.

EDIT:
the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
# check.sh
readonly unique_id="42"
unique_id="21"
```

give `0` if you execute `bash -n check.sh; echo $?` but execution itself results in the error message `./check.sh: line 4: unique_id: readonly variable`

Both behaviors are correct because this is not a syntax error but it will still break execution (even in unit tests) and I am asking if there is another way of precheck to filter out such errors.

Unittest will find only *expected* logical failures so this is not an alternative.

Comment: The two lines posted above are *erroneous*.  You need to remove spaces surrounding `=`.

Comment: Yep, you are right; I removed the blanks and add a shebang to get a real world example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you consider just run that script to check for errors? Then, if you wouldn't do some "errors" message to `stdout`, you could also check for last exit status code in bash: `$?`. (http://blog.yimingliu.com/2009/01/01/check-last-exit-status-code-in-bash-shell/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to place all your codes inside functions. That way you would be able to run your code and check for syntax errors before calling the main function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function A {
    ...
}

function B {
    ...
}

function main {
    # most of your codes here
    ...
}

# main "$@"
```

Uncomment the last line if no syntax errors were found. Of course there are exemptions like those executed on eval, nested paramater expansions or expansions basing on a runtime value, some which are based on arguments to a builtin command, and other errors found during runtime.

Comment: But you still execute the code...